# LESS: How access variable referenced by another variable who has a variable in its name?

Tags: css, variables, reference, less

As the title says, I need to access a variable content that is referenced besides having its name parametrized.

This is needed since the less library I'm using has referenced variables.

**SETUP:**

The due example since this is not clear if not explained with it:

The X library I'm using has this mixin:

```
.get-color-main-variables(@name) {
  @color-50:  ~"@{name}-50";
 // ... more lines to follow like the above.
}
```

Later on my code I use this mixin to get those variables:

```
.generate-raised-variant (@color) {
  .get-color-main-variables(@color);

  .color-@{color}-50 {
      color : @@color-50;
  }
}
```

So far so good, I can access those variables as pointed above.

**ISSUE:**

The issue is that I need to do set a lot of those styles, so I think of a generator mixin that generates them for me at Y intervals, so I did something like:

```
// Defining the generator.
.generator (@color, @step: 50) when (@size <= 1000) {
  .get-color-main-variables(@color);

  .color-@{color}-@{step} {
    color: @@color-50; // <------ ISSUE HERE!!!!!!
    // THIS DON'T WORK:
    // color: @@color-@step;
  }

  .generator(@color, @step + 50);
}

// And using it:
.generator(@color, 0);
```

I know that is a convoluted use of variables in less, but that is the bar that the library put off for me, so:

**QUESTION:**

The question/s would be:

- how can I access @@color-@step?
- or how can I accomplish that generator without having to specify manually all color steps I need?

Thanks

Comment: "how can I access @@color-@step?" - same way: `@var: "@{color}-@{step}";  color: @@var;` (you won't need `.get-color-main-variables` unless it's doing something else, so you could use it too but it will make  things more complicated).

Comment: (offtopic - what library is it? To add to my collection of "never write a code like this" :)

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thanks for your answer, can you post this as an answer so we can give it the proper follow up? Thanks

Comment: @seven-phases-max In @@color-100, "color" is a string, not a var, so I changed that to @var: '@color-@{step}'; and now it is getting the correct string value "@color-100" for instance, but it keep saying: `SyntaxError: variable @@color-100 is undefined`

Comment: @seven-phases-max The library is https://github.com/zavoloklom/material-design-color-palette/, which is good, this is the only issue I've encountered so far.

Comment: The error is  because you did not eliminate `.get-color-main-variables` call which is redundant if you use `@color` arg of you mixin directly (then assuming the original var name is `@mdc-red-300` the code becomes `@var: "mdc-@{color}-@{step}"; color: @@var;` - no need for double indirection as you can use single one (I did not use `mdc` prefix above because it was not in you example).

Comment: in other words the whole thing can be written as something [like this](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/oXMGYX?editors=110) (simplified) .

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thanks, I did thought of that, but was afraid in the future the var content gets renamed to something else :(

Comment: "the var content gets renamed to something else" - Very unlikely (because the variable names are hardcoded to "**m**aterial**d**esign**c**olor-[originalcolorname](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette)" (and even if it's renamed you have the name pattern in only one place) (technically for the code above you don't need any library - the whole palette can be written as a single 2-dimensional array (i.e. one Less variable) (and yes, color values are also very unlikely ever going to change)).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Sorry, but I don't think so. Is true that the var content is very unlikely to change, but is still a possibility, since the prefixes "mdc-" are prone to change in the future (maybe by setting them dynamically?).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Anyway, thanks for your help :) I really appreciate that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @seven-phases-max and a lot of trial and error I was able to accomplish this.

The following worked for me (despite of its weirdness):

```
.color-@{color}-@{step} {
    @buffer: 'color-@{step}';
    @color: @@buffer;

    color: @@color;
}
```